# CUDA compilation with relocatable code: "Could not find fatbin in ..."

Tags: cmake, cuda, nvcc

As part of a larger CMake project, I am adding a CUDA library. The rest of the project is C++, compiled with clang.

To test that the library works correctly, I'm creating a small executable and linking the CUDA library to it:

```
add_library(kernels STATIC
    kernels.cu
)
set_target_properties(kernels PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

# --- Test executable
add_executable(main
    main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE kernels)
```

The library compiles fine, but I get the following error when `nvcc` is invoked to do the device linking part of the process on my executable (target `main`):

```
nvlink fatal   : Could not find fatbin in '[some long path]/main.cpp.o'
nvlink fatal   : elfLink internal error
```

What is preventing this step from working?

Comment: `nvlink fatal   : Could not find fatbin in '[some long path]/main.cpp.o'` -- it would be impossible to have a fatbin file in a .cpp file, that would only be the case if you had a .cu file compiled to an object or if you took some deliberate steps to compile CUDA code in a .cpp file with nvcc, which I see no evidence of. I would guess something is badly broken in the compilation structure of your project or your CMake installation is old or hosed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce this issue in a fresh, tiny CMake project, so I eventually figured out that some flag from my larger project wasn't playing along.

It turns out that Thin LTO, which was enabled in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is causing this issue.
I disabled it for this particular target with:

```
target_compile_options(main PRIVATE "-fno-lto")
```